# Android: How do I stretch the fixed part of a 9 patch image from code?

Tags: android

I need to resize the fixed part from a 9 patch, not the part that resizes it's self, from code or some solution that doesn't need making a new image. Just setting width and height resizes resize the whole image, leaving the fixed part fixed.

Thx :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this can be done.